# Powershell Form Lag

Tags: forms, powershell

I am working on a reporting tool for my work.  The tool has 4 tables in it that refresh every few minutes.  When it refreshes it creates a background job to query new information for the next refresh.  During a manual refresh I want to grey out the tables, and have it wait for this background job to complete before resuming functionality. That all works great. (code below)

What has me completely confused and baffled is that the grey out process seems to lag.  When run by itself its instantaneous.  However with the sleep line afterwards it seems to do 1 table, then sleep a second.. then MAYBE 2 more.. then sleep a second.  And its consistent to the sleep interval.  Meaning if I set the sleep interval to 3 seconds, the staged grey'ing of my tables becomes staggered by 3 seconds instead of 1.

So I am looking for a better solution, and also wouldn't mind knowing how PowerShell can move to the next line of code before completing a previous one.

```
$myWindow.add_KeyDown({
    if ($_.keycode -eq "F5") {
        for ($i=0; $i-lt 4; $i++ ) {
            foreach ($row in $myDataGrid[$i].Rows) {
                $row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = "GRAY" 
                $row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = "BLACK" 
            }
        } 
        while ((get-job -Name "ticker").state -ne "Completed") {sleep 1}
        $out = Receive-Job -name "ticker"
        Get-Job -name "ticker" | Remove-Job
        refresh $($out) #updates the tables
        Start-Job -Name "ticker" -ScriptBlock $query -ArgumentList $args
    }
})
```

Comment: Are you using Windows Forms or WPF?